# iOS Automatically click and go to certain view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, automation

So I built my iOS app completely using code(built all interface programmatically). The app is pretty huge and every time I start the app, I need to click 3 or 4 times to go to certain view controller to see the effects.

Is there a way to auto this process?

So when I start the app, it will auto click button/table cell and go to certain view controller.

I can't set the initial view controller differently because I need to pass data from the beginning to the controller I want to see.

Thanks for help.

Comment: are you asking as to how to do this in an automation test sense, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **XCTest** framework to create automated test. You simply need to add new target in your projects settings. Then create a test case for any walkthrough of your application. The advantage is, after you change any part of your application, you can simply rerun the tests to see that you didn't break anything.

Xcode even has an option to record the tests, so you don't need to program it completely by hand.

Apples guide to UI testing:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/09-ui_testing.html

How to record UI tests:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/RecordingUITests.html

Comment: Is it possible to keep the app open after the XCTest? 
what happened is that the app close/quit after the test is complete.

Comment: Not as far as I know. You can add sleep() call to the end of the test which will let you use the app, although that is not very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegate pattern or blocks to wait until you get the data, then call your methods (If you know the button/ table cell indexpath) to go to your destination with the data. You can do the whole process programmatically.

Comment: It is possible. but I have to add a lot of extra in the view controller. The auto click thing is for development purpose, I don't want to add and delete later in the vc.